# Can't authenticate with created model on Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

In code with the comment "THIS IS NOT WORKING", I can't authorize.

I get user object and use `Auth::login($user)` but it doesn't work.

User in this moment creates in database.

```
  public function login(Request $request) 
  {
    if(Auth::check()) {
      return redirect('home');
    }
    if($request->isMethod('post')) {
      if($request->has('username') && $request->has('password')) {
        $inputs = $request->except('_token');
        if(!Auth::attempt(['username' => $inputs['username'], 'password' => $inputs['password']])) {
          $user = $this->registerUser($inputs);
          if($user) {
            Auth::login($user);
          }
        } 
      } 
      return (Auth::check()) ? redirect()->route('home') : redirect()->back()->with('form_error', true);
    }
    return view('pages.auth.login');
  }
```

User.php maybe here is something wrong?

```
namespace App\Models\system;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
    protected $primaryKey = 'uid';
    protected $table = 'eltk.dbo.system_users';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

Comment: wow, thats quite a mess. Maybe consider tidying up your code into other functions or methods. That can often help you find the problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's start step by step.

1. Why did you create user on a method where you need to handle just login logic?
2. What's the name of your database? Is it eltk or dbo or what? Define it in config/database.php under 'database' or in .env and use in model just table name, not name of the whole table, is not necessary.
3. In login method you need something like this:

   ```
   public function processLogin(Request $request){
   if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'active' => 1])){
       return redirect('/');
   }else{
       return redirect('login')->withMessage('User with this email and/or password does not exist or your account is not active.');
   }
   ```

   }

And btw, when you in if-else statement login user afterward you need to redirect him on some route.

Comment: Thank for advises :) i make a little refactoring in my code but still not working. If user is not created at beginning , than he can't authenticate, but after second time entering data - user authenticate successfully.

Comment: I found a problem, i using custom generated primary key ('uid' column), when i create user, system don't see generated on fly uid :( but after re-sending request, when user is already created - all works fine!

Comment: You need first to create two methods in your controller. One method for displaying view where user can register and the second one where did you save user to database and then your login method will work :)